# Multiple definition of variable First defined here error

Tags: c++, compile-time, multiple-definition-error

I have this c++ project with classes' definitions inside .hpp files and methods' declarations inside .cpp files.
The project uses a makefile to build and run.

The program ran without errors before but LinkedList didn't work as I wanted so I re-wrote it entirely.
Now LinkedList.hpp includes both the class definition and its methods' declarations.
I adjusted the other classes' methods so that they use LinkedList correctly.

Now when debugging the program I get this *multiple definition of, first defined here* error.

```
find: ‘lib’: No such file or directory
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g -Iinclude -o output/main src/Game.o src/Hero.o src/Title.o src/Level.o src/Menu.o src/Entity.o src/Window.o src/main.o src/Map.o src/Object.o -lncurses 
/usr/bin/ld: src/Hero.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: multiple definition of `TileTypeStr'; src/Game.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: src/Level.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: multiple definition of `TileTypeStr'; src/Game.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: src/Entity.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: multiple definition of `TileTypeStr'; src/Game.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: src/Map.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: multiple definition of `TileTypeStr'; src/Game.o:/home/user/projects/project-X-githubClone/projectX/include/Object.hpp:2: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:74: main] Error 1
```

So if I get this correctly, the problem is the multiple definitions of **const char* TileTypeStr[]**.
But why then when I change that array's name to, say,  **tts** the error message still reads "multiple definitions of **TileTypeStr**"?
and why if I comment out the only 2 references (including its declaration and initialisation) of this array inside the whole project the error message is still the same?

Comment: if you are using c++17  - add `inline` keyword before `const char* TileTypeStr[]`

Comment: The error does not change because the given command line does not compile anything, it links together previously compiled object files.

Comment: okay thanks @SegFault, I moved the definion of TileTypeStr[] from the .hpp file into the only method that uses it (in the associated .cpp file) to limit its scope, ran make clean and then make and everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TileTypeStr[]** was misplaced after all, moved it inside the toString() method I needed it for, then ran **make clean** to recompile all of the source files and **make** to build main.cpp.
By running make and not recompiling the source files I was stuck running the bugged version of the program.